# Difference between previous row

Tags: jquery

I have the following table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Diff</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2016</td>
    <td>65,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>59,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2014</td>
    <td>32,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Where the question marks are for DIFF and % I need to compare previous rows against each other and work out the difference in total and by percentage.

I relatively new to jquery and completely bewildered on how to achieve this.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: The downvotes you see are probably related to 1) Tag spamming (you have a lot of unnecessary or unrelated question tags) and 2) That this looks like homework and 3) You haven't shown any effort or attempts. SO users are more inclined to help if you show you've made some effort. There are a variety of basic jquery tutorials that will help you understand the basics of the language. Us doing this work for you would not serve any benefit to you as you wouldn't learn anything. Could you please try to make an attempt and show your work?

Comment: I completely understand and thank you for explaining, I will provide more examples of my code next time i.e. i'll make more of an effort...in reality for I was completely stuck on how to perform this function and had drawn a complete blank.

Comment: No problem. Don't let it discourage you, SO is heavily moderated for the benefit of all users that may come across these posts in the future. It's not meant as an affront to you, but simply a way to make the community better for everyone. Live and learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the non-header rows in `<tbody></tbody>`.

Then use [Array#prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to scan the rows in reverse, treating the first (ie last) row as a special case :

```js
$("table tbody tr").get().reverse().reduce(function(prevVal, tr, i) {
    var $tds = $(tr).find('td'),
        val = Number($tds.eq(1).text().replace(',',''))
  diff = val - prevVal;
    // console.log(val);
    $tds.eq(2).text((i > 0) ? diff : '-');
    $tds.eq(3).text((i > 0) ? ((100 * diff / prevVal).toFixed(1) + '%') : '-');
 return val;
}, 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Diff</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>2017</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2016</td>
    <td>65,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>59,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2014</td>
    <td>32,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's pretty trivial to add '+' symbols against positive values. I'm sure you can work that out for yourself

Answer (score 1):

Try this .Remove the `,` in td `innerhtml` using `replace()`.[`eq()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjp2KbVqMfVAhVGP48KHdv1AAYQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Feq%2F&usg=AFQjCNF421AWRe2A4OnKM21N9XQV5cUFMA) function used to find the particular index of the element on each row

```js
var total_val =parseFloat($('table tr').find('td').eq('1').text().replace(',',''))
$('table tr').each(function(){
var a = parseFloat($(this).prev('tr').find('td').eq(1).text().replace(',','')|0)-parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(1).text().replace(',',''))
$(this).prev('tr').find('td').eq(2).text(a)
$(this).prev('tr').find('td').eq(3).text((a / total_val) * 100+'%')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Diff</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2016</td>
    <td>65,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>59,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2014</td>
    <td>32,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply!, Shouldn't the results be on the next row? instead of -15000 shouldn't it be +15000 (PLUS) for 2017 80,000 +15000 18.75% as its comparing the difference year on year going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could use each to iterate through the rows of your table and `.prev('tr')` to get the previous row :

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){  
    var current_row = $(this);
    var previous_row = $(this).prev('tr');

    if( previous_row.html() ){

        //Compare 'previous_row' with 'current_row' here

    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){  
    var current_row = $(this);
    var previous_row = $(this).prev('tr');
    
    if( previous_row.html() ){
      //Exemple
      console.log('Compare ' + current_row.find('td:eq(1)').text() +' with '+ previous_row.find('td:eq(1)').text());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Diff</th>
      <th>Percentage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2017</td>
      <td>80,000</td>
      <td>?</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2016</td>
      <td>65,000</td>
      <td>?</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2015</td>
      <td>59,000</td>
      <td>?</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2014</td>
      <td>32,000</td>
      <td>?</td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add my own version - it's a lot less efficient than other answers but still.

```js
var totals = [];

//for each <td> in the table, select only those which are the second child of their <tr>
//i.e. ech value in the 'total' column
$("table td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {

  totals.push($(this).text().replace(/\,/g,''));
  //totals.push adds an item to the array 'totals'
  //$(this).text() selects the value of the current total being iterated
  //replace (/\,/g,'') gets rid of any commas (useful for finding out the difference later)
});

var i = 0;
var j = totals.length-2;
var k = totals.length-2;
var len = totals.length;
var diff = [];
var perc = [];

for (var i; i<len-1; i++) {
  diff.push(parseInt(totals[len-(i+2)]) - parseInt(totals[len-(i+1)]));
  //we're again adding each element we iterate over to the array of differences
  //totals[len-(i+2)] we take the first total and subtract the second from it
  //and we need to parseInt() to do maths on them (they are strings as-is)
  //and continue this doen the column, i.e. second minus third, etc.
  //and we have to go 'backwards' because we want a difference
  
  perc.push(Math.round(((parseInt(totals[len-(i+2)]) - parseInt(totals[len-(i+1)]))/(parseInt(totals[len-(i+2)])))*100));
}

$("table td:nth-child(3)").each(function() {
  //now we populate the 'diff' column with our already-worked-out values for the differences
  if (j==-1) { $(this).text("-"); return false; }
  //if we've reached the botttom of the column, the last value, there will be no difference nothing to compare it against)
  //so we just put a dash and terminate the 'loop' - 'return false'
  
  $(this).text(diff[j]);
  //for each thing being iterated over, give it the value of the correct item in the diff array
  j--;
  //we're again working backwards so we iterate backwards
});

$("table td:nth-child(4)").each(function() {
//and we do exactly the same as with the diff column
  if (k==-1) { $(this).text("-"); return false; }
  $(this).text(perc[k]+"%");
  k--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Diff</th>
    <th>Percentage</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2016</td>
    <td>65,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2015</td>
    <td>59,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2014</td>
    <td>32,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2013</td>
    <td>34,000</td>
    <td>?</td>
    <td>?</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```